# How to format bibliography references to avoid page overun?

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, citing

As the title suggests, some of my references are overrunning the page when a website is included. How do I make it wrap to the next line?

Example of problem:

[image: Website overrunning page]

Minimum example:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}



\begin{document}

\section{Abstract}
The future development of cities is critical for providing the spatial foundations for a society with cleaner modes of production and consumption \citep{aila2014,dpcd2009}.





\bibliography{My_Library}






\end{document}
```

and `My_library`:

```
@misc{aila2014,
  title = {2014 {{AILA VIC Award Winners}}},
  author = {{AILA}},
  year = {2014},
  howpublished = {https://www.aila.org.au/imis\_prod/AILAWeb/Chapters/VIC/2014\_AILA\_VIC\_Award\_Winners.aspx},
  journal = {Australian Institute of Landscape Architects}
}

@misc{dpcd2009,
  title = {Urban {{Design}}},
  author = {{DPCD}},
  year = {2009},
  month = jul,
  howpublished = {https://web.archive.org/web/20090703094547/http://www.dse.vic.gov.au/DSE/nrenpl.nsf/childdocs/-A8F9628C2B9FCDF8CA2572DA007DFD52?open},
  journal = {Department of Planning and Community Development}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap the URL in a `\url`, it works like a charm!

```
@misc{aila2014,
    title = {2014 {{AILA VIC Award Winners}}},
    author = {{AILA}},
    year = {2014},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.aila.org.au/imis\_prod/AILAWeb/Chapters/VIC/2014\_AILA\_VIC\_Award\_Winners.aspx}},
    journal = {Australian Institute of Landscape Architects}
}

@misc{dpcd2009,
    title = {Urban {{Design}}},
    author = {{DPCD}},
    year = {2009},
    month = jul,
    howpublished = {\url{https://web.archive.org/web/20090703094547/http://www.dse.vic.gov.au/DSE/nrenpl.nsf/childdocs/-A8F9628C2B9FCDF8CA2572DA007DFD52?open}},
    journal = {Department of Planning and Community Development}
}
```

[image: Working PDF File]

In the [documentation](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/exporting/scripting/) for the Zotero Extension "Better BibTeX" there is the possibility to add Javascript Code to set preferences for certain fields.
The first Sample shows how to add the `\url`-Tag before the URL in the `howpublished` field for BibTeX if the entry type is `webpage`. This might be changeable to for example `misc`.

```
if (Translator.BetterBibTeX && item.itemType === 'webpage') {
    if (item.url) {
        reference.add({ name: 'howpublished', bibtex: "{\\url{" + reference.enc_verbatim({value: item.url}) + "}}" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @talise! That certainly works. Do you know if there is a reason Zotero isn't doing this automatically and if there is a way to do this?  I'm exporting the library using better bibtex in Zotero.

Comment: I haven't used Zotero as well as Better BibTeX myself but I found a nice example in the [documentation](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/exporting/scripting/).
At the start there is a small explanation on how to add the Javascript to Better BibTeX. Further down you find Samples. The first one looks like your Problem and could solve it.
I also added the example in my answer!

Comment: Legend @talise! That's done it. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: That is great to hear! No Problem!